# Malformed command in kubectl run

Tags: powershell, docker, curl, kubernetes, kubectl

I have a Kubernetes cluster on which is deployed a replica of [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/accusoft/prizmdoc-server) image (but it's not important for the sake of the question).
Now, in Powershell I need to perform one REST request against the pod. In particular I have to send a `PUT` request to the endpoint `http://<POD_IP>:18681/PCCIS/V1/Service/Properties/Servers` passing this JSON payload:

`{"servers":[{"port":"18682","address":"10.244.1.29"}]}`

What I was trying to do is perform this action from within a [curlimages/curl](https://hub.docker.com/r/curlimages/curl) pod, just to be able to reach the pod's network. This is my attempt:

```
$PrizmDocPodIP="10.244.1.29"
$JsonPostBody='{"servers":[{"port":"18682","address":"10.244.1.29"}]}'
$cmd = "curl -i --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --request PUT --data '$JsonPostBody' http://$($PrizmDocPodIP):18681/PCCIS/V1/Service/Properties/Servers"
kubectl run -i --tty --rm curl --image=curlimages/curl --restart=Never "$cmd"
```

Unexpectedly, the command output this error:

```
curl: (3) nested brace in URL position 82:
curl -i --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --request PUT --data '{servers:[{port:18682,address:10.244.1.29}]}' http://10.244.1.29:18681/PCCIS/V1/Service/Properties/Servers
```

As you can see, the problem I have is that the string command I pass is not interpreted the right way and moreover the payload loses all the doublequotes of the JSON, that are important for the `curl` command to propertly work.

One another test I made is with this command (the `echo` is used to show what the `sh` command really would execute)

```
kubectl run -i --tty --rm curl --image=curlimages/curl --restart=Never -- sh -c "echo $cmd"
```

And the output is

```
curl -i --header Content-Type: application/json --request PUT --data {servers:[{port:18682,address:10.244.1.29}]} http://10.244.1.29:18681/PCCIS/V1/Service/Properties/Servers
```

Showing that the `cmd` Powershell variable loses its doublequotes when passed to `kubectl run`

What should be the right syntax to pass the `$cmd` command as is (preserving all its quotes and chars)?

Comment: Try with `"$cmd"` -> `"'$cmd'"` (single-quotes nested inside the doublequotes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution after some searching and trials.
First, I have to escape the double quotes in the `$JsonPostBody` variable.

```
$PrizmDocPodIP="10.244.1.29"
$JsonPostBody='{\"servers\":[{\"port\":\"18682\",\"address\":\"10.244.1.29\"}]}'
```

The other error is that the `curlimages/curl` Docker image executes the `kubectl run` arguments as the `curl`'s arguments, so I don't have to use the `curl` command:

```
kubectl run -i --tty --rm curl --image=curlimages/curl --restart=Never -- -i --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --request PUT --data $JsonPostBody http://$($PrizmDocPodIP):18681/PCCIS/V1/Service/Properties/Servers
```

This outputs

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
[1mDate[0m: Wed, 08 Jul 2020 13:23:30 GMT
[1mConnection[0m: keep-alive
1mContent-Length[0m: 0
```